# Flutter Error : A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

Getting error when using the slider in flutter.

Code where the error is :

```
 Slider(
                    value: (_currentStrength ?? userData.strength).toDouble(),
                    activeColor:
                        Colors.brown[_currentStrength ?? userData.strength],
                    inactiveColor:
                        Colors.brown[_currentStrength ?? userData.strength],
                    min: 100.0,
                    max: 900.0,
                    divisions: 8,
                    onChanged: (val) =>
                        setState(() => _currentStrength = val.round()),
                  ),
```

User data class :

```
class UserData {

  final String uid;
  final String name;
  final String sugars;
  final int strength;

  UserData({ required this.uid, required this.sugars, required this.strength, required this.name });

}
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NzQm.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are using Flutter with sound null safety enabled. The error message means that you are trying to assign a value which might be null to a parameter which may not be null.

You can probably fix your issue, by adding an exclamation mark to the value you are passing in like: `_currentStrength ?? userData.strength!`

But please read this: https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: Sry with adding '!' doesn't affect the problem but it says that I can remove the '??' operator which I don't want to remove.

Comment: Can you add the code snippet where userData gets declared? The problem seems to be that `strength` is nullable.